# Как в команду запроса данных из бд вводить название столбца

Tags: mysql

Я хочу чтобы пользователь вводил название столбца в строку и другой параметр и получал данные из бд.
Допустим, у меня есть два параметра в которые я помещаю данные из строк.

```
double st;
string st2;
```

И вот я пытаюсь отправить запрос в MAMP.

```
SELECT `значение st` FROM `название таблицы` WHERE значение st2;
```

Все выводится, все шикарно. И вот я этот запрос пытаюсь реализовать это в Visual Studio(я опущу некоторые моменты кода, поскольку они особого значения не имеют):

```
SELECT `@st` FROM `название таблицы` WHERE st2=@st2;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st2", st2);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st", st);
string st3 = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

В итоге на строчке string st3 = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar()); у меня программа останавливается и выдает ошибку

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "Unknown column 'st' in 'field list'"
```

Как это исправить? Я убирал заглушку, убирал кавычки, но это не помогло.